# JSON location storing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am converting JSON data into a list structure, and I want to save the "AAA.BBB[0].CCC.DDD[5].EEE" format as the id so when a user modifies the content of that list item it modifies the JSON data associated with that location.

For Example AAA.BBB[0].CCC.DDD[5].EEE = 123

123 is a list item but I want the id to be saved as "AAA.BBB[0].CCC.DDD[5].EEE"

Would there be a better way to save the location in the id?

*Edit:

Sample Code:

JSON DATA: {"AAA":{"AAB":"Value1","AAC":"Value2","AAD":1,"AAE":"Value3","AAF":"{"ABC": "Value4"}}}

Soo the id for list item "Value4" would be AAA.AAF.ABC

```
function nodeIT(obj,output){    
for (var x in obj){
    if(!(obj[x] instanceof Object)){

        //var str =JSON.stringify(obj);   // Where im stuck!
        output +="<li id='"+str+x +"'>";
        output += (x + "=" + obj[x] + "<br />");
        output +="</li>";
    }
    else if((obj[x] instanceof Object)){

        var obj1 = obj[x];
        output+="<li>" +x + "<ul>";

        output=nodeIT(obj1,output);
    }

}
output += "</ul></li>";
return output;
```

}

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using to create such a list structure? Maybe along with an example JSON string.

Comment: Instead of re-posting the same question twice, edit your original question to include more context/information to make it easier to answer.

Comment: I solved it. @KevinB wont happen again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the ID attribute and being forced to use a single string, you could take advantage of jQuery's `.data()` method, which lets you associate javascript objects with html elements.

So you do something like this when you're building the list elements:

```
var liElement = $('<li />')
    .text(x + "=" + obj[x])
    .data({
        container: obj,
        key: x
    });
```

And then access the data later like this (where `this` refers to an `li`):

```
var container = $(this).data('container');
var key = $(this).data('key');
var value = container[key];
// .. modify value
container[key] = value;
```

Please see a full example here: http://jsfiddle.net/h38Ec/

Comment: Thanks. The only problem that I run into with that is, the JSON data I listed is just an example, the actual JSON data I am using in my code is really extensive, to the point where there can be duplicate values. The reason I am trying to go with location is because thats a hard location for where the data is stored in reference to the actual JSON data and there cannot be multiple in one location. So I didn't specify.

Comment: @judomonkeykyle I don't understand the problem you're describing. Can you give an example of some data that causes a problem with this method, but works with an absolute location method?